# how to add progress bar while webservice call?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

while running this code I'am getting Null Pointer error! Please give me solution.

```
\\............
new LoginCheck().execute(txt_username.getText().toString(),txt_password.getText().toString());
.............//

class LoginCheck extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    protected String         doInBackground(String... params) {

        String responsetring = "";
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Logincheck");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            request.addProperty("username",params[0]);
            request.addProperty("password",params[1]);
            //Msg("Version"+appversion+"AppName"+Appname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + "Logincheck", envelope);
            } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Msg(e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            SoapPrimitive response;
            try {
                response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                responsetring = response.toString();
            //    Msg(responsetring.toString(), 1);
            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Msg(e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            String[] splitrows = responsetring.split(";");
            String usernamestr = "";
            String deviceid = "";
            String isanydevice = "";

            if (responsetring.equals("false")) {
           //     Helper.InfoMsg("Alert", "Please Check userame and password and confirm device is valid", LoginActivity.this);

            } else {
                usernamestr = splitrows[0];
                deviceid = splitrows[1];
                isanydevice = splitrows[2];
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (deviceid.equals(tm.getDeviceId().toString())) {
                    LoginActivity.this.username = usernamestr;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
                } else {
                    TelephonyManager tm1 = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
              //      Helper.InfoMsg("Your Device Id", (tm1.getDeviceId().toString()), LoginActivity.this);
                    txt_warning.setText((tm1.getDeviceId().toString()));
                    if (isanydevice.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        LoginActivity.this.username = usernamestr;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
                    } else {
                    //    Helper.warning("Sorry", "Not Allowed To Login  Other devices", LoginActivity.this);
                        // return false;
                    }
                }

            }
            //return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Msg(e.toString(), 1);
            //  return false;
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }






}
```

Comment: Where null pointer exception?

Comment: please post your logcat @prabhu

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:165)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:110)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:82)
            at com.scm.androscm.LoginActivity$LoginCheck.<init>(LoginActivity.java:185)

Comment: at com.scm.androscm.LoginActivity$1$1.run(LoginActivity.java:165)
            at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4713)
            at com.scm.androscm.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:162)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you have missed out in Asynctask is that, you have forgot to override onProgressUpdate() method. onProgressUpdate() method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. I have given a sample code here. Refer it. Hope it might helpful to you.

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) 
{        
    progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}
```

P.S: Also refer below link.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/612017/Android/Mobile/AsyncTask-show-progress-bar

Comment: Thank you so much for your support.The error has been cleared and my project is running now!

Comment: accept the answer if it was helpful to you. I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In onPreExecute :

```
 AlertDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
```

In onPostExecute

```
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

In onPreExecute()

```
private ProgressDialog pdia;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading, Please Wait...");
        pdia.show();
    }
```

In onPostExecute()

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
        pdia.dismiss();
}
```

Over all code :

```
class LoginCheck extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private ProgressDialog pdia;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading, Please Wait...");
        pdia.show();
    }

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String responsetring = "";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Logincheck");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        request.addProperty("username",params[0]);
        request.addProperty("password",params[1]);
        //Msg("Version"+appversion+"AppName"+Appname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + "Logincheck", envelope);
        } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Msg(e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        SoapPrimitive response;
        try {
            response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            responsetring = response.toString();
        //    Msg(responsetring.toString(), 1);
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Msg(e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        String[] splitrows = responsetring.split(";");
        String usernamestr = "";
        String deviceid = "";
        String isanydevice = "";

        if (responsetring.equals("false")) {
       //     Helper.InfoMsg("Alert", "Please Check userame and password and confirm device is valid", LoginActivity.this);

        } else {
            usernamestr = splitrows[0];
            deviceid = splitrows[1];
            isanydevice = splitrows[2];
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (deviceid.equals(tm.getDeviceId().toString())) {
                LoginActivity.this.username = usernamestr;
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
            } else {
                TelephonyManager tm1 = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          //      Helper.InfoMsg("Your Device Id", (tm1.getDeviceId().toString()), LoginActivity.this);
                txt_warning.setText((tm1.getDeviceId().toString()));
                if (isanydevice.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                    LoginActivity.this.username = usernamestr;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
                } else {
                //    Helper.warning("Sorry", "Not Allowed To Login  Other devices", LoginActivity.this);
                    // return false;
                }
            }

        }
        //return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Msg(e.toString(), 1);
        //  return false;
    }
    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);
        pdia.dismiss();
}
```